# SQL CASE Statement Change Column name in THEN clause

Tags: sql-server

Is there anyway that I can change column name through THEN clause in CASE STATEMENT. This is how my code looks but it is not working.

```
 SELECT 
     CASE 
        WHEN @IDWeeklySpecial = '107' 
           THEN 
              CASE 
                 WHEN ISNULL(v.blnLeftHandDrive, 0) = 1 
                    THEN [HANDEDNESS] = 'LHD' 
                    ELSE [HANDEDNESS] = 'RHD' 
           ELSE 
              CASE 
                 WHEN ISNULL(v.blnLeftHandDrive, 0) = 1
                    THEN STEERING = 'LHD' 
                    ELSE STEERING = 'RHD' 
             END 
     END
```

I want this result

[My Ideal Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8okJy.png)

Is this achievable? If so how?

Comment: You have several nested `CASE` statements and the syntax is wrong.  Can you show us, by way of sample data, what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Are you trying to do all this in `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: I already updated the question hopefully this would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible...  if you are asking about dynamically modifying the column name in the *resultset*.

The CASE expression returns a *value*.  To a specify the column name in the resultset, assign an alias.

```
  SELECT CASE ... END AS mycolname
       , ... 
    FROM ...
```

The column name is determined when the statement is parsed and prepared. The *execution* of the statement cannot modify the column name.

---

(It's possible I didn't understand the question. It's not clear what OP is tying to achieve.)

Comment: I see thanks, but do you have any option I could do this fix this issue?

Comment: One thing I already knew to fix this issue is through using dynamic query however i'm trying to avoid those things.

Comment: @AlvinQuezon: One option would be to do the conditional test *outside* of the SELECT statement. Write two separate SELECT statements, with different aliases assigned to the column. And let the conditional test decide which of the two SELECT statements to execute.

Answer (score 2):

`case` is an *expression*.  You can name the column before or after an expression, but not in the middle.

Also, a SQL statement needs to return a fixed set of columns, including the column name.

So, you cannot do what you want with a simple SQL statement.  You could use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = '
SELECT (CASE WHEN COALESCE(v.blnLeftHandDrive, 0) = 1
             THEN 'LHD'
             ELSE 'RHD'
         END) as [columnname]
. . . ';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[columnname]',
                   (case when @IDWeeklySpecial = '107' then 'HANDEDNESS' else 'STEERING' end)
                  );

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note that the `. . .` is for the rest of your SQL query.

Comment: columns in resultset are fixed at statement PREPARE time, cannot be modified at execution time +10

Answer (score 0):

I can't digest your select statement, but assume its inline case

```
SELECT item_name = CASE WHEN item_name = 'sometext' THEN item_id ELSE item_name END AS MyColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to assign differing column names in your query, because all vertical data values in the result set belong to the same column.

If you are just trying to alias a column name while using the CASE expression, ensure that the AS is used after the END keyword. Others have mentioned this, but it was the problem in my case. Changed it to something like this and it worked:

```
CASE  
    WHEN table1.Name LIKE '%John%' THEN 'Some John Person' 
    WHEN table1.Name <> 'NULL' THEN table1.Name
    ELSE 'Nobody' 
END AS NewAliasColumnName
```